# Unable to load and fetch variables from group_vars file from /etc/ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am trying to fetch the variable value from group_vars but ansible is unable to locate it from the default location `/etc/ansible`. Here are the details.

Ansible Version

```
[admin@ansicontrol newvarsexample]$ ansible --version
ansible 2.9.18
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/admin/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.8.2 (default, Feb 28 2020, 00:00:00) [GCC 10.0.1 20200216 (Red Hat 10.0.1-0.8)]
```

Ansible Inventory file `/etc/ansible/hosts`:

```
[stack]
192.168.47.130
```

Ansible Playbook `fedoragroupvarfile.yaml`:

```
- hosts: all
  remote_user: admin
  tasks:
    - name: Set OS distribution dependent variables
      include_vars: "os_{{ ansible_facts['distribution'] }}.yaml"
    - debug:
        var: fedcharm
```

Ansible group_vars file `/etc/ansible/group_vars/os_Fedora.yaml`:

```
fedcharm: "This is Fedora 32 OS variable file"
```

Error

```
TASK [Set OS distribution dependent variables] *******************************************************************************
fatal: [192.168.47.130]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {}, "ansible_included_var_files": [], "changed": false, "message": "Could not find or access 'os_Fedora.yaml'\nSearched in:\n\t/home/admin/practiceansible/newvarsexample/vars/os_Fedora.yaml\n\t/home/admin/practiceansible/newvarsexample/os_Fedora.yaml\n\t/home/admin/practiceansible/newvarsexample/vars/os_Fedora.yaml\n\t/home/admin/practiceansible/newvarsexample/os_Fedora.yaml on the Ansible Controller.\nIf you are using a module and expect the file to exist on the remote, see the remote_src option"}
```

Why does `include_vars` try to find the variables file in the current playbook's directory rather than the default `/etc/ansible/group_vars` location where the file is located.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "default location" is where ansible looks for the inventory if you don't specify one with `-i /path/to/inventory.yaml`, but a file you include with `include_vars` is not an inventory, but only contains bare variables.
If you use `include_vars` with a relative path, ansible will look for the file in a location relative to the playbook/role (see [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_vars_module.html)).
You can specify an absolute path in `include_vars` as well. E.g. `/etc/ansible/variables.yaml` (the file has to exist).

But actually, I don't think that is what you want. If you have your variables in `/etc/ansible/group_vars`, they will be loaded by default without `include_vars` if you structure your directories correctly. Check the [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#organizing-host-and-group-variables).

Place a file containing this line in `/etc/ansible/group_vars/stack.yaml`:

```
fedcharm: "This is Fedora 32 OS variable file"
```

And `fedoragroupvarsfile.yaml` should contain this:

```
- hosts: all
  remote_user: admin
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: fedcharm
```

Then run your playbook as before. If you did everything correctly, ansible will load the variables for the group `stack` in your inventory from `/etc/ansible/group_vars/stack.yaml` and display the correct message.

Comment: Thanks @toydarian.. yes, if i place the variables file within the playbook current directory it works and the group_vars without the include_vars works fine. But the only thing confuses me is with the following documetation - https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html#playbooks-tips-and-tricks

Comment: which part exactly?

Comment: Doc - https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html#playbooks-tips-and-tricks. The last part "This pulls in variables from the group_vars/os_CentOS.yml file". I was assuming it pulls from the /etc/ansible default location. But i got your point now.. thank you @toydarian

Comment: This documentation is actually a little bit confusing and can be understood in a wrong way. Summary: The inventory will look for group variables in `group_vars` relative to the inventory, while `include_vars` always looks relative to the role/playbook if the path is relative. Does my answer answer your question? If that is the case, please feel free to  accept it :)

Comment: yes.. its clear now.. already upvoted your answer.. :)

Comment: Please click the tick-icon, so people know that the question is answered ;)